# Redux-toolkit redux-persist not work on mobile or safari desktop

Tags: reactjs, safari, redux-persist, mobile-browser, redux-devtools

I am developing a platform for which I am using react-redux-devtools and redux persist to persist the state of the application, everything is perfect, even if I access it from localhost:3000/ in safari it works perfectly. When I test it in the deploy is when the problem comes.

My App.js file is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {store} from "./app/store";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const persistor = persistStore(store)


root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
      </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The code of my store file

```
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {persistReducer} from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import articulosReducer from '../features/articulos/traerArticulosSlice'
import titulos_normasReducer from '../features/normas/traerNormasSlice'
import normaActivaReducer from '../features/normas/normaActivaSlice'
import articuloSeleccionadoReducer from '../features/articulos/articuloSeleccionadoSlice'
import usuarioLoginReducer from '../features/usuarios/loginUsuarioSlice'
import crearUsuarioReducer from '../features/usuarios/createUsuarioSlice'
import crearNormaSlice from '../features/normas/crearNormaSlice'
import {CookieStorage} from "redux-persist-cookie-storage";
import Cookies from 'cookies-js'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: new CookieStorage(Cookies, {}),
    whitelist: ['titulos_normas', 'usuario']
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    usuario: usuarioLoginReducer,
    titulos_normas: titulos_normasReducer,
    articulos: articulosReducer,
    normaSelected: normaActivaReducer,
    articuloSeleccionado:  articuloSeleccionadoReducer,
    crearUsuario: crearUsuarioReducer,
    crearNorma: crearNormaSlice
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer : persistedReducer,
    middleware: [thunk]
})
```

To make redux-edvtool and persist works on mobile and safati web browser